How can I migrate XML content?
I have a XML structure as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<accordion>
    <title>Facts</title>
    <description></description>
    <items>
        <item>
            <subheading>Test</subheading>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices
                dui.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <subheading>consectetur adipiscing elit</subheading>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mattis rhoncus urna
                neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Ut porttitor leo a diam. Auctor neque vitae
                tempus quam pellentesque.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <subheading>Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus</subheading>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis.
                Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut
                eu sem integer vitae.&lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;Vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Nec ullamcorper sit
                amet risus nullam eget felis. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit. Sed viverra tellus
                in hac habitasse platea.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
        </item>
    </items>
    <disclaimer></disclaimer>
</accordion>

I have migrated each item inside items as a paragraph named accordion_item with a migration file for paragraph.
I have another migration file in which I want to migrate the XML into a block content type and file looks like:
id: accordion_dct
label: 'Accordion Block Migration'
migration_tags:
  - 'Accordion'
migration_group: migration_phase_one
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - modules/custom/migration/data/Accordion/default.xml
  item_selector: /accordion
  fields:
    - name: title
      label: 'Title'
      selector: 'title'
    - name: description
      label: 'Description'
      selector: 'description'
    - name: disclaimer
      label: 'Disclaimer'
      selector: 'disclaimer'
    - name: accItems
      label: 'Accordion Items'
      selector: 'items'
      
  ids:
    title:
      type: string

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: accordion_block_type
  info: title
  field_accordion_title: title
  field_accordion_subtitle: description
  field_accordion_disclaimer: disclaimer


  acc_items_array:
    plugin: xml_items
    source: accItems

  field_accordion_content:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: '@acc_items_array'
    process:     
      target_id:
        -
          plugin: migration_lookup
          migration: accordion_dct_paragraph
          source: subheading
          no_stub: true
        -
          plugin: extract
          index:
            - 0
      target_revision_id:
        -
          plugin: migration_lookup
          migration: accordion_dct_paragraph
          source: subheading
          no_stub: true
        -
          plugin: extract
          index:
            - 0
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:block_content'

migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - accordion_dct_paragraph

acc_items_array in the file is an array of all the subheadings and descriptions from the XML and I am using subheadings as IDs.
The migration runs but only one paragraph is connected to the field 'field_accordion_content'.
How would I make the field 'field_accordion_content' reference to the multiple item from XML?

You are writing the same number into target_id and target_revision_id. I don't know the lookup result, but I guess you want extract array key 1 for the revision id.

It was an issue with the field itself. It was set to have just 1 item as a reference to  the paragraph.
